# Shoutcast 1.9.9beta protocol

Tags: protocols, shoutcast

My app is able to stream Shoutcast stations, however today I found out that some of the stations use server version 1.9.9beta and my app can't start streaming them, it just fetched header information. There must be an important change between previous server versions. Does anyone aware of this change?

Comment: There actually isn't.  The protocol for connecting and playing back data hasn't changed.  Can you post a link to an example station?

Comment: @Brad http ://95.211.60.38:6006

Comment: @Brad you can see the behaviour by using ffmpeg too: ffmpeg -i http ://95.211.60.38:6006 Using shoutcast addresses broadcasting with other versions, you'll see the result immediately, however using this version will make ffmpeg wait for a long time. I think there is an undocumented change which occurs on header or end of header...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.9.9beta server cannot handle "Range" header. This is a bug on the server.